# How can I optimize drawing Core Graphics grid for low memory?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, out-of-memory, ios9, core-graphics

In my app, I draw a grid in a custom view controller. This gets embedded in a scroll view, so the grid gets redrawn from time to time after the user zooms in or out (not during zooming).

The problem is, I'm trying to optimize this method for low-memory devices like the iPad Mini, and it's still crashing. If I take this drawing away entirely, the app works fine, and it doesn't give me a reason for the crash; it just tells me the connection was lost. I can see in my instruments that memory is spiking just before it crashes, so I'm pretty certain this is the issue.

The view is 2.5 times the screen size horizontally and vertically, set programmatically when it's created. It has multiple CALayers and this grid drawing happens on several of them. The crash happens either immediately when I segue to this view, or soon after when I do some zooming.

Here are my drawing methods (somewhat simplified for readability and because they're pretty redundant):

```
#define MARKER_FADE_NONE 0
#define MARKER_FADE_OUT 1 // fades out at widest zoom
#define MARKER_FADE_IN 2 // fades in at widest zoom

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if (layer == gridSubdividers) [self drawGridInContext:ctx spacing:1 lineWidth:1 markers:NO fade:MARKER_FADE_NONE];
    if (layer == gridDividers) [self drawGridInContext:ctx spacing:5 lineWidth:1 markers:YES fade:MARKER_FADE_OUT];
    if (layer == gridSuperdividers) [self drawGridInContext:ctx spacing:10 lineWidth:2 markers:YES fade:MARKER_FADE_IN];
}

// DRAW GRID LINES
- (void)drawGridInContext:(CGContextRef)context
                  spacing:(float)spacing
                lineWidth:(NSInteger)lineWidth
                  markers:(BOOL)markers
                     fade:(int)fade
{
    spacing = _gridUnits * spacing;

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor gridLinesColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);

    float top = 0;
    float bottom = _gridSize.height;
    float left = 0;
    float right = _gridSize.width;

    // vertical lines (right of origin)
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    for (float i = _origin.x + spacing; i <= _gridSize.width; i = i + spacing) {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, i, top);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, i, bottom);
    }
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGPathRelease(path);
    }
```

...then I repeat this for() loop three more times to draw the other lines of the grid. I also tried this slightly different version of the loop, where I don't create an individual path, but instead just add lines to the context and then stroke only at the very end of all four of these loops:

```
for (float i = _origin.x + spacing; i <= _gridSize.width; i = i + spacing) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, i, top);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, i, bottom);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I also tried a combination of the two, in which I began and stroked within each cycle of the loop:

```
for (float i = _origin.x + spacing; i <= _gridSize.width; i = i + spacing) {
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, i, top);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, i, bottom);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
```

So how can I streamline this whole drawing method so that it doesn't use as much memory? If it can't draw one path at a time, releasing each one afterward, like the first loop I showed above...I'm not really sure what to do other than read the available memory on the device and turn off the grid drawing function if it's low.

I'm also totally open to alternative methods of grid drawing.